# extendedEdgesForLayout Missing from UIViewController

Tags: ios, ios7

In WWDC Video 2013 #201 "Building User Interfaces", it mentions a UIViewController method called extendedEdgesForLayout that controls whether a view controller's views extend to full screen or not.

For example, it says you could set this property to UIExtendedEdgesNone so that your view controller's view wouldn't overlap with the top of the screen.

But, I cannot find this method in the latest UIViewController documentation, or the UIViewController.h file. So, did they just change to something else, without updating the video? What should I be using to get the same behavior?

Comment: It's `edgesForExtendedLayout` and `UIRectEdgeNone`. A quick scan of the `UIViewController` docs would have revealed this information.

Answer (score 0):

I got caught by this too. The API in the video, `extendedEdgesForLayout` has changed to [`edgesForExtendedLayout`](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/edgesForExtendedLayout).

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) UIRectEdge edgesForExtendedLayout
```